# Wildfly - 404 not found on my WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, http-status-code-404, wildfly

I've a web service packaged in a `.war` and which has the following structure :

```
-> META-INF
|  -> maven
|  -> MANIFEST.MF
-> WEB-INF
|  -> classes
|  -> lib
|  -> beans.xml
|  ...
-> wsdl
|  -> filldatabase.wsdl
|  -> filldatabase_schema.xsd
```

When I put this archive inside my `standalone/deployments` folder of my wildfly server, that works but if I want to display the WSDL through the browser, it's return me `404 Not Found`

The `soap address` used to be typed in my browser is te following (precised in my filldatabase.wsdl file) :

`<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/dataRecovery/services"/>`

Some additional informations :

my function in java :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://dataRecovery/", portName = "FillDataBasePort", serviceName = "FillDataBaseService")
public class FillDataBase {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "fillDataBase", action = "urn:FillDataBase")
    @RequestWrapper(className = "dataRecovery.jaxws.FillDataBase", localName = "fillDataBase", targetNamespace = "http://dataRecovery/")
    @ResponseWrapper(className = "dataRecovery.jaxws.FillDataBaseResponse", localName = "fillDataBaseResponse", targetNamespace = "http://dataRecovery/")
    @WebResult(name = "return")
    public void fillDataBase() throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: So, http://localhost:8080/dataRecovery/services?wsdl does not work?

Comment: Indeed, this URL does not work also